# Problem with Music Details

Tags: mp3, music, windows-media-player, id3

I have some music files and the information doesn't show up. Here they are in explorer:

[image]

As you can see, there is no information for track, title, artist, or album. This prevents me from syncing the music with Windows Media Player or iTunes. However, here's one of the empty tracks in MP3Tag:

[image]

As you can see in the details panel **and** on the right, those MP3 files have titles, artists, albums, and even tracks and album artwork. I opened those same MP3 files in 2 other ID3 editors, and still they have all the data. I've saved the data to the MP3 files on all the editors, but Windows *still* won't recognize it for *just* those files. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Windows Media Center on Vista/7 both
>   support ID3v2.4 because they use Media
>   Player internally.  I don't know about
>   Windows XP Media Center Edition.

[Source](http://old.nabble.com/Windows-and-ID3v2.4-tags---what-I-use-td26807455.html)

> In Windows Vista and Win7, they only
>   component I know of that doesn't
>   support  ID3v2.4 is the shell
>   (explorer.exe).  To have tag info
>   displayed in Windows  Explorer, you'll
>   need to use ID3v2.3 tags, or older, as
>   you already know.

To know which tag version you're using in Mp3Tag, check the `Tag` column:

[image: Tag Column]

(if not available, right-click on it and customize your columns)

[image: Customizing columns]

Then, to change the tag version that is going to be used in your files, go to `Tools->Options->Tags->Mpeg.`

[image: id3v2 tag versions]

For more information about id3 [check official website](http://www.id3.org/ID3v2Easy).

Comment: I had similar problems before and tried this exact approach. While I found it to work often, it is not always successful, sometime some broken / incorrect tags seem to remain in the music file.

Comment: Doesn't work for me, all my songs are listed as ID3v2.3, the ones with information and the ones without. :(

Comment: Try to delete all tags and insert them again. Do a backup first of your files. If you're still having problems with tag editing, try to use foobar2000 http://www.foobar2000.org/, a **great** audio player with tag editing capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe windows only reads one specific version of the mp3 tag system (ID3v1.1, ID3v2.3 or ID3v2.4).

I don't know that particular software your use, but there should be an option somewhere to save (or replicate) the data to a different version. Try that, and see if it helps.

Comment: Or replicate to the other tagging system. Winamp has this I think.

Comment: @ChrisF: Yep indeed, that's what I mean. It should also be possible with the software the OP uses (http://www.mp3tag.de/en/).